# Can gcc's thread-local storage share cache lines across threads?

Tags: linux, gcc, cpu-cache

If a variable or constant-sized array is declared with __thread, can the backing virtual address range share a cache line across threads? (For example, if two copies of a thread-local integer land on the same cache line, performance will suffer because of cache line bouncing.) Does the answer depend on gcc/Linux version and hardware architecture?

Answer (score 3):

According to Ultrich Drepper who is an infamous expert former glibc maintainer, "not allocated in the normal data segment; instead each thread has its own separate area where such variables are stored. The variables can have static initializers. All thread-local variables are addressable by all other threads but, unless a thread passes a pointer to a thread-local variable to those other threads, there is no way the other threads can find that variable. Due to the variable being thread-local, false sharing is not a problem—unless the program artificially creates a problem."

If you study, [Memory part 6: More things programmers can do](https://lwn.net/Articles/256433/) thread local variables, if a pointer is passed, could be accessing the same cache line.

To avoid this issue, simply don't pass the addresses in question around.  As specific technique of grouping frequent rw variables together to share a cache line in a struct is described, with padding to AVOID multiple threads writing to same cache line when NOT using TLS, so long as the __thread variable pointers are not used by other threads, cache line bouncing ought be avoided.

Hopefully the linker implementers know the CPU architecture, you can't choose where in virtual & physical memory address space the multiplied thread local storage is allocated, it ought be safely assumed they plus CPU designers do a reasonable job of avoiding performance problems due to false clashes.  You'ld have the same issues happening by accident between seperate processes, nevermind threads if cache associativity bounces was a common problem.